# Multiples SQL Subqueries in one SQL query?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I couldn't end up retrieving data from multiple tables in a single query.

I have the following tables:

[image]

A brief explanation :

- A student can study many subjects and subjects can be studied by many students (table Study Created)
- A subejct is taught by a lecturer (FK used in (table Subject))
- The table Grade gives infos about the marks obtained by a student

The SQL query I was trying to perfom is: Retrieve average students who study subjects taught by lecturer Antonio.

So first I used an AVG aggregation on table grade to get average students:

```
SELECT Id_Student, Name, AVG(Mark) 
AS Average FROM Grade 
GROUP BY Id_Student, Name
```

But my trouble is also to use the result of this SQL query and filter with again with the result of Subjects taught by Lecturer "Antonio".

Is it possible to make it in a one SQL query?

Comment: your example data is inconsistent.

Comment: agreed.  it's VERY hard to try to interpret.  also awful naming etc. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Id_Student, Name, AVG(Mark) AS Average FROM Grade
where id_student in 
(
    select student.id_student from subject
    join study on subject.id_subject = study.id_subject
    join student  on study.id_student = student.id_student
    where subject.taught_by = L1
)
GROUP BY Id_Student, Name
```

also you could probably just join GRADE instead of doing the subselect that I did here.  But it's hard to tell how it will go without actually testing it.

Comment: Thanks myte! sorry for the awful example :)